# Django filtering AND loop in a Django on M2M field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a **list** of IDs I need to query and filter **(using AND)** in Django. I would like to use something along the lines of **example 2** below but it gives incorrect results 0. The models are simple, Many Products can have Many Tags. What is wrong with example 2?

Correct Results

Example 1:

```
  q = Product.objects.all()
                for id in _list_of_ids:
                    q.filter(tags__id=id)
```

Example 2:

Incorrect results but seems better `(edited for brevity)` ...

```
for id in _list_of_ids:
     q = Q(tags__id=id)
     # apend q here etc

# q = (AND: ('tags__id', 1), ('tags__id', 2))
Products.objects.filter(q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is:

```
products = reduce(lambda qs, p_id: qs.filter(tags=p_id), _list_of_ids, Product.objects.all())
```

Basically there is a difference between a single `.filter` call with several `Q` objects and multiple `.filter` calls each one with a single `Q` object.

In the first scenario you get one inner join with all `Q` filters applied to it.

In the second scenario you get many inner joins, each applying only one `Q` object.

In your case, when you are searching for a product, having a combination of multiple tags, you need to make an inner join per tag in order to find such a product (this is the second scenario) so you need many `.filter` calls.

More about that in the docs: [Spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

What is the full code for Example 2?

Something like this seems like it should work...

```
q_expression = [Q("tags__", id) for id in list_of_ids]
queryset = Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_expression))
```

Comment: That look good! I get an error ``too many values to unpack (expected 2)`` on the line ``Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_expression))``. list_of_ids output is  ``['10', '5']``

Comment: looks like the q_expression ``[<Q: (AND: tags__, 10)>, <Q: (AND: tags__, 5)>]`` has the ``,`` still

Answer (score 0):

```
q = Product.objects.filter(tags__id__in=list_of_ids)
```

Comment: That will not do AND

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood.